# How to Read the Latest rss feed in android?

Tags: android

I am doing one project and i want to read the latest rss feeds and i want dispaly,i ahve read lot of blogs about reading rss feeds.

But all of them given reading only the html or xml,but i want ro read diffarent one,and i have given link below ,plz if any buddy know help me

```
 http://onsoranje2012.mobgen.com/?mod=feeds&action=coach
```

thanks in advance .

Regards,
Gangadhr

Answer (score 0):

Android people already done some Sample application on RSS Feeds.
Just refer the below link. you will be got some idea and go head with those Examples
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/index.html